# What is the cost of WeakRef in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, memory-management, weak-references

I am wondering what it the overhead of using [WeakRef](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/index.html) processing large data set?

The task I want to perform is something like this:

```
huge = get_array_of_weak_refs # 100000000 entries or more :)
result = huge.length * huge.inject(0) { |accum, it| accum += it.total } # much more complicated, just a sample
```

Assuming that `get_array_of_weak_refs` is not time consuming and has `O(1)` complexity. So that only concern is the memory size of the `huge` array.

I also don't care at the moment about the time it takes to compute the `result`.

If the `huge` is a normal array, then of course it might just not fit in the memory.

But would it help if WeakRef would be used as elements of that array? So that after we have iterated over an element `x` it can be garbage collected to free up some memory.

What is the overhead for this scenario? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use weak references here? They won't help, and are not designed for such scenario.

Instead set up an iterator (an object that responds to `each`) that loads the data in chunks.

Comment: Loading data in chunks will still keep all the objects in memory as long as `huge` variable is used.

Comment: But your process is iterative so you don't need to store the whole `huge` in memory, right?

Answer (score 3):

The cost of WeakRef can be very high. WeakRef extends the Delegator class and in the 1.8 implementation Delegator objects are very heavy. Every time you instantiate a Delegator, every method in the wrapped object gets redefined. Wrapping a String with a Delegator will allocate ~2800 objects and use ~90K of memory. This make WeakRef's unusable in many cases since they are very slow to create and may use more memory that the objects they are pointing to.

Delegator has been fixed in the 1.9 Ruby code, however, there is a bug where WeakRef's may end up pointing to the wrong objects, so their use is unsafe.

If you want to use weak references you can use the ref gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/ref). This gem gets the overhead down to <1K of memory per reference. If you use Jruby or Rubinius, the implementations are even more efficient.